# Serializing BSON stream in Node.js

Tags: node.js, serialization, tcp, bson

I have a Node.js tcp server that receive BSON objects over stream and I would like to read every time the whole BSON object from the `BSON.DeserializeStream` ([MongoDb npm](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/bson.html)).

The problem is when the BSON object is big I don't get the whole object on the [`data` event](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable) and therefore I can't deserialize it (I get corrupted message error):

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
// The data is partial and cannot be sent to the BSON.Serializer
})
```

I don't know if its possible to get the whole BSON object like `.NET serializers` or I will have to manage the parts until I receive the whole message (Send the first 4 bytes as the message length and then don't try to deserialize the object until the whole message received.

Comment: Are the BSON length announced before sent or separated by something like i.e. a null byte?

Comment: Ive ended up sending the length of the BSON data before each BSON data sent.